# Javafx calculate button with an item and price parallel array

Tags: javafx

I'm having trouble getting a subtotal from my selections of my combobox. I am creating a restaurant app that someone chooses an item from a combobox and then that item is added to a listbox. As the item is added I am trying to store those items into an array list. Then take that array list and add the prices together for a subtotal. I can add what ever item is selected to the array. So 1 item. I cannot total the items up either to print a subtotal. Can someone please give me a hand with this. I have been at this for 2 days now and I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

```
    double bcost [] = { 1.95, 1.50, 1.25, 2.95, 2.50, 1.50 };
    double acost [] = { 5.95, 6.95, 8.95, 8.95, 10.95, 12.95, 6.95 };
    double mcost [] = { 15.95, 13.95, 13.95, 11.95, 19.95, 20.95, 18.95, 13.95, 14.95 };
    double dcost [] = { 5.95, 3.95, 5.95, 4.95, 5.95 };
    String [] beverages = { "Soda", "Tea", "Coffee", "Mineral Water", "Juice", "Milk" };
    String [] appetizers = { "Buffalo Wings", "Buffalo Fingers", "Potato Skins", "Nachos", "Mushroom Caps",
            "Shrimp Cocktail" };
    String [] maincourse = { "Seafood Alfredo", "Chicken Alfredo", "Chicken Picatta", "Turkey Club", "Lobster Pie",
            "Prime Rib", "Shrimp Scampi", "Turkey Dinner", "Stuffed Chicken" };
    String [] dessert = { "Apple Pie", "Sundae", "Carrot Cake", "Mud Pie", "Apple Crisp" }; 

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ComboBox<String> beverageComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    ObservableList<String> items1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(beverages);
    beverageComboBox.getItems().addAll(items1);

    Label bo = new Label("Beverage Ordered");
    pane.add(bo, 2, 5);

    ListView<String> list1 = new ListView<>();

    beverageComboBox.setOnAction((e) -> {
        list1.getItems().add(beverageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    });

    list1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
        list1.getItems().remove(list1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    });

    pane.add(list1, 3, 5);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list1, 5);
 // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ComboBox<String> appetizerComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    ObservableList<String> items2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(appetizers);
    appetizerComboBox.getItems().addAll(items2);

    Label ao = new Label("Appetizer Ordered");
    pane.add(ao, 2, 10);

    ListView<String> list2 = new ListView<>();

    appetizerComboBox.setOnKeyPressed((e) -> {
        list2.getItems().add(appetizerComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    });

    list2.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
        list2.getItems().remove(list2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    });

    pane.add(list2, 3, 10);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list2, 5);

   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Button cal = new Button("    Calculate Bill    ");

    // Setting an action for the Calculate button btn.setOnAction(new
    cal.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

            double tax = 0.00;
            double total = 0.00;

            ArrayList<Double> cal = new ArrayList<Double>();
            if (ActionEvent.getSource() == beverageComboBox) {
                cal.add(bcost[beverageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()]);
                double subtotal = 0;
                for (Double price : cal) {
                    subtotal += price;
                }

                // subtotal = cal;
                // tax = subtotal * .07;
                // total = subtotal + tax;

                tst.setText(Double.toString(subtotal));

                tt.setText(Double.toString(tax));
                tto.setText(Double.toString(total));
            }
        }
    });

    pane.add(cal, 3, 30);
```

Comment: Please state exactly the challenge you are having. Items are not being added to the array list? You're unable to sum the arraylist values?

Comment: I can add what ever item is selected to the array. so 1 item. I cannot total the items up either to print a subtotal

Comment: Sorry I don't understand many portions of the code, but what i would do in this case is to create a HashMap to keep track of the cost of each item added to the cart. Once an item is added to the cart, create a copy in the hashmap - product and price. It would be easier to iterate through the hash map values and sum the prices

Comment: `if (ActionEvent.getSource() == beverageComboBox) {` ??? Even if there was a static `getSource` method in `ActionEvent`, the `source` of a `onAction` event on the `cal` `Button` would never be the the `beverageComboBox` `ComboBox`... Furthermore you shouldn't store product name & price in different arrays, but store them in one object. Moreover `double` cannot represent all prices accurately (unless you use integral values e.g. cents...)

Comment: Yes but don't I have to use an array list for the combo box. That means I have to have a parallel array 1 for prices one for items. How would I use that object for the combobox???

Comment: As @SUNNYben said. Use a HashMap:
`static HashMap<String, Double> beverage = new HashMap<>();
static{
    beverage.put("Soda", 1.95);
    beverage.put("Tea", 1.5);
    // ...
}
`
Notice that the static block will be executed when the class is loaded by the JVM.

Comment: I've never used a hash map where would that block of code be inserted??